# Determine the limit distribution

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution

I have this question here that I could use some help with.

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, . . . be a sequence of random variables such that $P(X_n=\frac{k}{n})=\frac{1}{n}$, for $k=1,2,...,n$

Determine the limit distribution of $X_n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Now I think that if I could find $f_X(x)$ and $F_X(x)$ for $X_n$ then I would have no problem. I guess then you can just use limits or the characteristic function to find the limit distribution. But I'm having a hard time finding them. Anyone that has some idea where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: If $x \in (0,1]$  we must have $\frac{k-1}{n} < x \leq \frac{k}{n}$ for some $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and so $P(X_n \leq x) = \frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n}$. Can you identify the limit $P(X_n \leq x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? What would finding this limit imply?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand how you arrived at your result but I'll have to sleep on it and see if I can calculate the limit tomorrow.

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, for a first post I think yours was good. It stated a well-defined problem and showed some thought, explaining where you needed help. As for the answer, the notation obfuscates a simple picture. Note that $P(X_n \leq 2) = P(X_n \leq 2.41) = P(X_n \leq 2.9999) < P(X_n \leq 3).$ If you agree that $P(X_n \leq k/n) = P(X_n = 1/n) + \dots + P(X_n = k/n) = k/n$, then you can plot those points of the cdf $F^n_X(x) \dot = P(X_n \leq x)$.