# Limit distribution, cant quite get right answer.

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, probability-distributions

There's a question in my book that I can't quite get the hang of. I searched the forum and found someone asking an identical question, unfortunately I did not understand the answers given on that thread so I figured that I can ask you guys for help!

The question goes:

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ ...$ be a sequence of random variables such that $P(X_n =  \frac k n)  =  \frac 1 n$ , for $k = 1, 2, \dots, n$. Determine the limit distribution of $X_n$ as $n \to \infty$.

According to the book we have that the limit distribution is $U(0,1)$!

I do know the definition for limit distributions but I haven't solved many problems with it. Can someone please help me? :)

Comment: What definition does the book give for limit distribution? Can you try to apply it?

Comment: And you might want to give the link to this identical question of which you did not understand the answers and explain why you did not understand them; that way we will not give the same answers. :-)

Comment: $Xn$ converges in distribution to the random variable $X$ as $n → \infty$ iﬀ  $F_X_n(x) → F_X(x)$ as $n → \infty$ for all $x \in C(F_X)$, where $C(F_X) = {x : F_X(x)$ \  is \ continuous \ at \ x} = the continuity set of $ $F_X.$ Notation: $X_n \ d → \ X$ as $n → \ \infty$.  @Bib-lost

Comment: and the link : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960178/determine-the-limit-distribution  @Bib-lost

Comment: Thanks! Check out Cm7F7Bb's answer below and let us know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of the convergence in distribution, the sequence $X_n$ converges in distribution to the random random variable $X\sim U(0,1)$ if
$$
P(X_n\le x)\to P(X\le x)
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb R$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $P(X_n\le x)=P(X\le x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $P(X_n\le x)=P(X\le x)=1$ for $x\ge1$, we only need to investigate the case when $0<x<1$. We have that
$$
P(X_n\le x)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nI_{(-\infty,x]}(k/n)}{n}=\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}n
$$
for $0<x<1$, where $I_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$ and $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function. Since the ratio of $\lfloor nx\rfloor$ and $nx$ tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\ne 0$,
$$
\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{nx}\cdot x\to x
$$
as $n\to\infty$. The proof is complete.

Comment: this is a good answer, but i get the feeling that one have to assume that $X \in U(0,1)$ before any proof can be made, is there no method to show this without first assuming that $X \in U(0,1)$? @Cm7F7Bb

Comment: @Janono We find the pointwise limit of $P(X_n\le x)$ and then we determine that the pointwise limit is the CDF of the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.